# Volvo S40 seemingly transmission failure

Tags: transmission, volvo, axle

I've got a Volvo S40, 2.4L, automatic, model year 2007, with 95k kms.

Lately I had my front axle replaced because I had significant vibration at specific speeds. I've also got serviced (oil, filters), had my alternator replaced, and the PCV manifold replaced (it was leaking). All of this took place at the same bike shop.

Today I was in the middle of overtaking, had my shifter in manual mode and shifted down from 5th to 3rd. Suddenly I've lost all acceleration and had to perform emergency menuvears and braking to avoid an accident.

Luckily no collision happened, and I was able to safely stop the car.

When stopped, the engine was fine, and I was able to shift between the gears. When in neutral or parking, the car was fine.

In D or R, no power was transferred to the wheels and the car m5adr awful (but not loud) noises. When moving back to parking, there was a loud click/tap noise.

My assumption is that the transmittion was in a bad shape overall and the sudden load of two downshift + full throttle was the last straw.

However, another theory could be that the mechanic that changed my front axle (due to vibrations on acceleration) just two weeks ago did something wrong, thus causing the described behavior.

Without any further inspection at the moment, is there any chance that the car failed due to the mechanics work, or is it completely unjustified to blame him for it?

Comment: By “front axle” do you mean one of the front drive shafts with the CV joints on?

Comment: Yes, the CV joints

Comment: Have you checked the fluid level in the trans?

Comment: If one of the cv joints has detached, then you will loose drive and will likely hear banging noises.  I would give them a check first.

Comment: @moab no, i haven't